# What is the difference in converting string buffer to string using .toString(), String.valueOf() and + " "

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

What is the main difference in conversion of StringBuffer to String for the following three cases :

Case 1 : Using toString()

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Welcome");
String st = sb.toString();
```

Case 2 : Using + ""

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Welcome");
String st = sb + "";
```

Case 3 : Using String.valueOf()

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Welcome");
String st = String.valueOf(sb);
```

Which is best practice to use in performance wise ?

Comment: Nothing really, sb + "" means call the toString method of the StringBuffer class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Welcome");
String st = sb + "";
```

will result more or less in

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Welcome");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append((sb == null) ? "null" : sb.toString());
builder.append("");
String st = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Is builder.append(""); in forth line required??

Comment: @RajavelD I would argue `toString`

Comment: @RajavelD The first one, but it's unnoticeable. I just like the way it reads better.

Comment: Only if this wasn't done within a loop ;) +1 otherwise

Comment: @user3505725 Yeah. The `String` in the concatenation expression could've been anything, even `null` assuming it was cast to `String`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it compiles to `new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(sb)).append("").toString()`, but close enough

Comment: @Bohemian That's effectively what happens, but [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) only says that `null` reference is converted to `"null"`, but not how. Edited to account for that. Thanks.

Comment: @Bohemian - Why `String.valueOf(sb)` ?. Why not `sb.toString()` ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If the string is null , you will get null pointer exception in third line itself..Isn't it?

Comment: @user3505725 With what I originally put yes. The real story gives a better result of converting the `null` to the `String` `"null"`.

Comment: My point is that forth line builder.append(""); is not necessary..Can you show me any difference when I remove it ?

Comment: @user3505725 What if the `String` was `"whatever"` or actually came from a non-constant expression? The compiler doesn't make any distinctions in this case, so that line is required.

Comment: @TheLostMind because `sb` could be `null` and the compiler (which creates that code) doesn't know/care if `sb` will be null or not. `String.valueOf()` handles `null` by returning `"null"`)

Comment: Can you explain Case 3 : Using String.valueOf() also

Comment: @raja It's basically what Bohemian just said. `valueOf` makes sure if one of the operands is a null reference, it'll gets transformed to the string value `"null"` instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 6):

If we compile them into two methods in java

```
private StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Welcome");

public String testToString() {
  return sb.toString();
}

public String testAppend() {
  return sb + "";
}
```

and then use `javap -v`, we get

```
public java.lang.String testToString();
  descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #19                 // Field sb:Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
       4: invokevirtual #27                 // Method java/lang/StringBuffer.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
       7: areturn       
    LineNumberTable:
      line 10: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0       8     0  this   Lcom/stackoverflow/Question;

public java.lang.String testAppend();
  descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: new           #31                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #33                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
       7: aload_0       
       8: getfield      #19                 // Field sb:Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
      11: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      14: invokevirtual #38                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      17: areturn       
    LineNumberTable:
      line 14: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      18     0  this   Lcom/stackoverflow/Question;
```

So appending appears to be slightly less efficient as it uses an extra bit of stack and contains more instructions.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use "javap -v"

Comment: It's a command line tool that ships with the JDK. javap -v myclass.class